# Submodule of $\mathbb{Z}$-module with the same rank

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, algebraic-number-theory

For a $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M$ in the field of algebraic numbers, suppose that it has a $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule $N$ which has the same rank with $M$. Shall one deduce that $M=N$? Or can anyone please supply to me some counterexamples?

Comment: $2 \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Aphelli Thank you.